# how to create function in oracle, that the result of this function we can use in ANY

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP 
(
  ID VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) 
, TXT CLOB 
) 


create or replace FUNCTION get_field_keys (field CLOB)
  RETURN  type_array_of_varchar2
IS
  return_value  type_array_of_varchar2;
BEGIN
  //do some split operations(already done)
  //return_value[] = 'a';
  //return_value[] = 'b';
  //return_value[] = 'c';
  //..
  return return_value;
END;
```

this function must return value, that we can do

```
select * from TEMP where 'a' = ANY(get_field_keys(TXT))
```

return value of function get_field_keys must be set of varchar2, I tried varray, but "ANY" doesn't work by this way. It must be record or something else.

Comment: a small qn: what is type_array_of_varchar2 in your example...

Answer (score 2):

Since your function seems to be returning a `TABLE` or `VARRAY` type, you can use it in an unnesting expression:

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE 'a' IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_field_keys(TXT))
```

I'm not sure if this will work also with the `ANY` quantifier, but it shouldn't matter to your goals, whether you use `ANY` or `IN`